# C++ Forward declaration and pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, pure-virtual

I have a problem using forward declaration and virtual functions. I got the following error message during compilation.

```
main.cpp:131: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Database::MySQL’
database_mysql.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Database::MySQL’:
database.h:28: note:    virtual void Database::Interface::query(const char*, QueryResult&)
database.h:29: note:    virtual void Database::Interface::query(std::string, QueryResult&)
database.h:30: note:    virtual bool Database::Interface::step(QueryResult&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)
```

The compiler said these functions are still pure virtual functions, but I declared and defined them properly. I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my source code.

```
// database.h
class QueryResult;

namespace Database
{
    class Interface {
        public:
            Interface() {};
            virtual ~Interface() {};

            virtual void query(const char *sql) = 0;
            virtual void query(std::string sql) = 0;
            virtual void query(const char *sql, QueryResult &result) = 0;
            virtual void query(std::string sql, QueryResult &result) = 0;
            virtual bool step(QueryResult &result,
                              std::vector<std::string> &row) = 0;
    };
}

// database_mysql.h 
namespace Database
{
    class MySQL : public Interface {
        public:
            class QueryResult {
            public:
                QueryResult();
                ~QueryResult() ;
                void set(MYSQL_RES *result);
                MYSQL_RES *get();

            private:
                MYSQL_RES *_result;

            };

            ...

            void query(const char *sql);
            void query(std::string sql);
            void query(const char *sql, QueryResult &result);
            void query(std::string sql, QueryResult &result);
            bool step(QueryResult &result, std::vector<std::string> &row);

            ...
    };
}


// database_mysql.cpp
Database::MySQL::QueryResult::QueryResult()
    : _result(NULL)
{
}

Database::MySQL::QueryResult::~QueryResult()
{
    ...
}

void Database::MySQL::QueryResult::set(MYSQL_RES *result)
{
    ...
}

MYSQL_RES *Database::MySQL::QueryResult::get()
{
    ...
}


void Database::MySQL::query(const char *sql)
{
   ...
}

void Database::MySQL::query(std::string sql)
{
   ...
}

void Database::MySQL::query(const char *sql, QueryResult &result)
{
   ...
}

void Database::MySQL::query(std::string sql, QueryResult &result)
{
   ...
}

/* @return: false on done or true if remained rows exist */
bool Database::MySQL::step(QueryResult &result, std::vector<std::string> &row)
{
    ...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to show what is at main.cpp:131 so we can help you. Your concrete class is correctly defined, but I suspect that you're not instantiating the object correctly.
Also, as pointed out by @anders, your QueryResult class should belong to the Interface.h file.

Comment: @Edison Gustavo Muenz: This error can be reproduced by trying to create an instance of class `Database::MySQL`

Answer (score 3):

Because of the forward declaration compiler is looking for the class `QueryResult` in the global namespace. The function you defined in class `MySQL` use the inner class (which is inside the namespace) `QueryResult`. This is treated as an *overloading* by the compiler and not as the implementation of the pure virtual function. My suggestion to solve this is to remove the forward declaration and make the `QueryResult` a inner class of interface `Interface` (it makes sense to put it there, otherwise there is no use of the interface). Then it will compile properly.

Comment: Thanks. hmmm... I used forward declaration to make that there are different QueryResult classes depends on SQL APIs like a database_sqlite3.h, etc. But I think it's not possible if I put the QueryResult class into the Interface class.

Comment: Probably you can make `QueryResult` also an abstract base class so that different implementation of `Interface` can provide their own implementation of `QueryResult`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now, but how can I receive different database handle in the member function parameters of abstract base class? Should I use void pointer or template class? Sorry for my poor question. I am C++ newbie. :-)

Answer (score 1):

move the decl "QueryResult" into the namespace Database::Interface

it seems to be an issue with name spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the problem is still remained with same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a quick fix now by making QueryResult a class and deriving `MySQLQueryResult` from it. As others pointed out the issue is with compiler not being able to use a nested class instead of the forward declared class.

```
        // database.h
        class QueryResult {
        //make this class abstract by creating a protected default constructor
        protected:
          QueryResult(){}
        }

        //mysql.cpp
        class QueryResult : ::QueryResult {
        public:
            QueryResult();
            ~QueryResult() ;
            void set(MYSQL_RES *result);
            MYSQL_RES *get();

        private:
            MYSQL_RES *_result;

        };
```

Comment: Is it possible to call functions of MySQLQueryResult using QueryResult reference? How can I declare MySQLQueryResult parameters on the Interface's member functions without forward declarations?

Comment: Your `QueryResult` base class should contain members that are applicable to all implementations of `Interface`, so `QueryResult` should contain the least common denominator functions/attributes in it.